# Incorrect output due to incorrect declaration?

Tags: java

I am executing the code to display Prime numbers from 1 to 100. When I execute the below code, it does not show all numbers. Here is the code

```
public class PrimeNumberSeries {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         boolean flag = true;
        for(int i=1; i <= 100; i++){
                for(int j=2; j<= i-1; j++){
                  if(i%j==0){
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag == true){
                System.out.println("The number is prime number. Value = "+ i);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I am confused about declaration of the flag variable. The program shows me a correct output if I declare the variable inside the first for loop, that is,

```
for(int i=1; i <= 100; i++){
                 boolean flag = true;
                    for(int j=2; j<= i-1; j++){
```

What is the reason behind it?
If the variable is declared as a Class variable (`static boolean flag`) above the main method, then also it displays the same output.

Comment: Not the declaration, but the initialization is the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the second one is correct.

Problem in first version is because sometimes `flag` has not been changed in loop, so initialisation value is used.
Say in different way: has value for previous (or some of previous) checking.

Or in pseudo-code correct algorithm is:

```
for every number from 1 to 100
   assume is prime
   check, maybe have dividor -> not prime
   print
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialising `boolean flag = true;` inside the forLoop for `i`, ensures that for each increment of `j`, again the `flag` is assigned value `true`. That's what is correct implementation, as you are assuming that initially the number: `i` is primeNumber and when you find any divisor of it, you make `flag=false`

Comment: Thanks for the concise and accurate explanation! It helps a lot.

Comment: My Pleasure Sir, Please accept the answer if you are satisfied and close the question.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that, when declaring your `boolean flag` outside of your loop, it is not being reset to `true` for each `Integer i`. So once the `boolean flag` gets changed to `false` it will remain `false` for each `Integer i` after that. Declaring it inside of your loop makes sure it gets reset to `true` everytime.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the programing logic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check j value till j<=i-1

```
for(int j=2; j<= i-1; j++)
```

You just need till **j <= Math.sqrt(i)**

Following is little optimized solution for your use case.

```
int  n=100;
System.out.println("All Prime Numbers Between 1 to "+n);
boolean isPrime;

for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    isPrime = true;
    for (int j = 2; j <=Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isPrime)
        System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```